# how to get the id to open dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have the following code

```
<td><a href="#" id="dialog_link-19" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Click here</a></td>
<td><a href="#" id="dialog_link-25" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Click here</a></td>
<td><a href="#" id="dialog_link-33" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Click here</a></td>
<td><a href="#" id="dialog_link-556" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Click here</a></td>
```

`#dialog_link` is generated dynamically.

in my js I need to know which was clicked.

this is my js

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        // Dialog Link
        $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            $.ajax({
                  url: "teams/pp",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: 
                  success: function( data ){

                     console.log(data);

                    }

                });

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: I'm confused. Where in this code do you need to know which box was clicked? And if the ID is generated automatically, does ('#dialog_link').click do anything? It seems like it wouldn't get anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the id of the one which was clicked liek this:

```
$('a[id*=dialog_link]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `id^` instead of `id*`, `id^` used to indicate that the `id` beginning with the given text and `id*` matches if the given text is available in the `id`, anywhere even at last like `id1-dialog_link`:

```
$("td a[id^='dialog_link']").click(function(){ 
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Here `a[id^='dialog_link']` will match `dialog_link-19` but not `id1-dialog_link`.

Comment: is this getting more upvotes than mine because of the use of prop? I think people misunderstand when prop should be used. Straight from the JQuery prop() page: For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

Comment: I think there is another difference in our answers and it's selector string, you used `$('a[id*=dialog_link]')` that means any id containing this word `dialog_link` anywhere within the id and mine is `$('a[id^=dialog_link]')` that means only ids that begins with the word `dialog_link`.

Answer (score 2):

This should return the number of the link clicked:

```
$('a[id*=dialog_link]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('dialog_link-','');
    alert(id);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/8DXSh/1/)

I have used the `.replace()` function to remove the text